# How to convert string in format "Wed Oct 11 08:27:33 CEST 2023" to date in Java

Tags: java, date

I need to convert `String` which is in format `"Wed Oct 11 08:27:33 CEST 2023"` to date in Java.

I tried to use below but it is throwing parsing error.

```
String dateString = "Wed Oct 11 08:27:33 CEST 2023";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss XXX yyyy");
formatter.parse(dateString);
```

Frankly speaking, I am not sure how to handle `"CEST"` part

Comment: Stop using outdated classes like`SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date` move over to the more modern `java.time` API

Comment: Please add the stacktrace

Comment: In general you should avoid using timezone abbreviations (like CEST).  They are often ambiguous.   For example, CST can mean 3 different timezones.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations

Comment: That string is the output from the `toString` method of the outdated `java.util.Date`  class. If you can get hold of the original `Date` object, convert with `yourDateObject.toInstant()` and make any further conversions from there, and you need no parsing. If you can get only the string, use [the good answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77227619/5772882). This question has been asked before. I will search for an original and close this question once I find one.

Comment: Nitpickng, from @StephenC’s link: *"CST" can mean China Standard Time (UTC+8), Cuba Standard Time (UTC−5), and (North American) Central Standard Time (UTC−6), and it is also a widely used variant of ACST (Australian Central Standard Time, UTC+9:30).* I count 4 in the quote.

Comment: @OleV.V. -  I live in Australia and I used to live in that timezone ... and CST is >not< commonly used in Australia.  Certainly, not these days.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not forced to deal with large amounts of legacy code that makes heavy use of `java.util.Date` and you are using a Java version of 8 or higher, you are best adviced to use `java.time`, even if the desired result must be a `java.util.Date`.

Here's an example that uses `java.time` and produces a `java.util.Date`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String input = "Wed Oct 11 08:27:33 CEST 2023";
    // define a formatter for the input including a locale
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu",
                                Locale.ENGLISH
                            );
    // parse the input using the formatter
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, dtf);
    // print it
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(input, dtf));
    // convert it to a java.util.Date
    Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
    // print the Date, too
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Output:

```
2023-10-11T08:27:33+02:00[Europe/Paris]
Wed Oct 11 08:27:33 CEST 2023
```

---

If you have to use `java.util` and `java.text` for this task, then use a `z` in order to parse the time zone name (`CEST` for *Central European Summer Time*) and better add a `Locale.ENGLISH`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String input = "Wed Oct 11 08:27:33 CEST 2023";
    // create a matching parser
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                Locale.ENGLISH
                            );
    // parse the String
    Date date = sdf.parse(input);
    // print the Date
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Output:

```
Wed Oct 11 08:27:33 CEST 2023
```

Comment: While we still encounter a few cases where we need an old-fashioned `Date` for a legacy API, no one needs to use the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` (except I once met an API that required me to pass a `SimpleDateFormat` instance as argument for reasons that I never understood; but that definitely doesn’t seem to be the case here).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have seen tasks in universities that required the students to use Java 8 **and** also required them to solve tasks using `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` exclusively… Facepalm, I know… But sometimes you have to do what you were told to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", I  have tried the following and it works!

```
String dateString = "Wed Oct 11 08:27:33 CEST 2023";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
formatter.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: Don't encourage the use of superseded classes like `SimpleDateFormat`